# how to set the default value to the list box using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to set the this as a default value for my list box  can any body help me out.

thanks

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            var targetid = '<%:ViewData["target"] %>';
            if (targetid != null) {
                $("#lstCodelist").val(targetid); //// I need to set this targetid as default selected value for lstCodelist
            }
```

Comment: Is #lstCodelist a select list?

Comment: Yes Dan its a select list. thanks

Comment: BTW, `targetid` will never be null; at worst, it will equal an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set **n** to the index of the item you wish to set as selected.

```
$("#lstCodelist option").eq(n).attr('selected','selected')
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$('#foo').val(2)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yRXEc/

Comment: Thanks Dan, But I need to something like to set it up default select item.$("#lstCodelist option").eq(n).attr('selected','selected')

Answer (score 0):

$("#ListBox")[0].selectedIndex = 0

Answer (score 0):

It is worked for me. You can try it

```
$("#foo").val("")
```